# Correct HTTP request method for nullipotent action that takes binary data

Tags: rest, http, post, get, asp.net-web-api

Consider a web API method that has no side effects, but which takes binary data as a parameter. An example would be a method that tells the user whether or not their image is photoshopped, but does not permanently store the image or the result on its servers.

Should such a method be a `GET` or a `POST`?

`GET` doesn't seem to have a recommended way of sending data outside of URL parameters, but the behavior of the method implies a `GET`, which according to the HTTP spec is for safe, stateless responses. This becomes particularly constraining under the semantics of REST, which imply that `POST` methods create a new object on the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This becomes particularly constraining under the semantics of REST, which imply that POST methods create a new object on the server.

While a `POST` request means that the entity sent will be treated "as a new subordinate of the resource identified by the Request-URI", there is no requirement that this result in the creation of a new **permanent** object or that any such new object be identified by a URI (so no new object as far as the client knows). An object can be transient, representing the results of e.g. "Providing a block of data, such as the result of submitting a form, to a data-handling process" and not persisting after the entity representing that object has been sent.

While this means that a `POST` **can** create a new resource, and is certainly the best way to do so when it is the server that will give that new resource its URI (with `PUT` being the more appropriate method when the client dictates the new URI) it is can also be used for cases that delete objects (though again if it's a deletion of a single* resource identifiable by a URI then `DELETE` is far more appropriate), both create and delete objects, change multiple objects, it can mean that your kitchen light turns on but that the response is the same whether that worked or failed because the communication from the webserver to the kitchen light doesn't allow for feedback about success. It really can do anything at all.

But, your instincts are good in wanting this to be a `GET`: While the looseness of `POST` means we can make a case for it for just about every request (as done by approaches that use HTTP for an RPC-like protocol, essentially treating HTTP as if it was a transport protocol), this is inelegant in theory, inefficient in practice and clumsy in definition. You have an idempotent function that depends on solely on what the client is interested in, and that maps most obviously the `GET` in a few ways.

If we could fit everything in a URI then `GET` would be easy. E.g we can define a simple integer addition with something like `http://example.net/addInts?x=1;y=2` representing the addition of `71` and `2` and hence being a permanent immutable resource representing the number 3 (since the results of `GET` can vary with changes to a resource over time, but this resource never changes) and then use a mechanism like HTML's `<form>` or javascript to allow the server to inform the client as to how to construct the URIs for other numbers (to maintain the HATEOS and/or COD constraints). Simples!

Your problem here is that you do not have input that can be represented as concisely as the numbers `1` and `2` can above. In theory you could do something like `http://example.net/photoshoppedCheck?image=data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU…` and hence create a URI that represents the resource of the results of the check. This URI will though will have 4 characters for every 3 bytes in the image. While there's no absolute limit on URI length both the theory and the practice allow this to fail (in theory HTTP allows for proxies and servers to set a limit on URI length, and in practice they do).

An argument could be made for using `GET` and sending a request body the same way as you would with a `POST`, and some webservers will even allow you to do this. However, `GET` is defined as returning an entity describing the resource identified in the URI with headers restricting how that entity does that describing: Since the request body is not part of that definition it **must** be ignored by your code! If you were tempted to bend this rule then you must consider that:

1. Some webservers will refuse the request or strip the body, so you may not be able to.
2. If your webserver does allow it, the fact that its not specified means you can't be sure an upgrade won't "fix" this and so break your code.
3. Some proxies will refuse or strip the request.
4. Some client libraries will most certainly refuse to allow developers to send a request body along with a `GET`.

So it's a no-no in both theory and practice.

About the only other approach we could do apart from `POST` is to have a URI that we consider as representing an image that was not photoshopped. Hence if you `GET` that you get an entity describing the image (obviously it could be the actual image, though it could also be something else if we stretch the concept of content-negotiation) and then `PUT` will check the image and if its deemed to not be photoshopped it responds with the same image and a `200` or just a `204` while if it is deemed to be photoshopped it responds with a `400` because we've tried to `PUT` a photoshopped image as a resource that can only be a non-photoshopped image. Because we respond immediately, there's no race-condition with simultaneous requests.

Frankly, this would be darn-right horrible. While I think I've made a case for it by the letter of the specs, it's just nasty: REST is meant to help us design clear APIs, not obtuse APIs we can offer a too-clever-for-its-own-good justification of.

No, in all the way to go here is to `POST` the image to a fixed URI which then returns a simple entity describing the analysis.

It's perfectly justifiable as REST (the `POST` creates a transient object based on that image, and then responds with an entity describing that object, and then that object disappears again). It's straight-forward. It's about as efficient as it could be (we can't do any HTTP caching† but most of the network delay is going to be on the upload rather than the download anyway). It also fits into the general use-case of "process something" that `POST` was first invented for. (Remember that first there was HTTP, then REST described why it worked so well, and then HTTP was refined to better play to those strengths).

In all, while the classic mistake that moves a web application away from REST is to abuse `POST` into doing absolutely everything when `GET`, `PUT` and `DELETE` (and perhaps the WebDAV methods) would be superior, don't be afraid to use its power when those don't meet the bill, and don't think that the "new subordinate of the resource" has to mean a full long-lived resource.

---

*Note that a "single" resource here might be composed of several resources that may have their own URIs, so it can be easy to have a single `DELETE` that deletes multiple objects, but if deleting X deletes A, B & C then it better be obvious that you can't have A, B or C if you don't have X or your API is not going to be understandable. Generally this comes down to what is being modelled, and how obvious it is that one thing depends on another.

†Strictly speaking we can, as we're allowed to send cache headers indicating that sending an identical entity to the same URI will have the same results, but there's no general-purpose web-software that will do this and your custom client can just "remember" the opinion about a given image itself anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It's a difficult one. Like with many other scenarios there is no absolutely correct way of doing it. You have to try to interpret RESTful principles in terms of the limitations of the semantics of HTTP. (Incidentally, I don't think it's right to think of REST having semantics, REST is an architectural style which is commonly used with HTTP services, but can be used for any type of interface.)

I've faced a similar situation in my current project. We chose to use a `POST` but with the response code being a `200` (OK) rather than the `201` (Resource Created) usually returned by RESTful Web APIs.